Retrieve send identifier from Whatsapp message using Ampscript
In e-mail we can retrieve JobID, BatchID right from Ampscript, allowing us to do whatever we want with it.
We have a use case where we need to match the Entry Data Extension row with the Whatsapp Sends Status related to it, but I don't see any common identifier to do that report.
If we were able to retrieve the SendIdentifier before sending I could just save that information to a Data Extension and that would change everything...

We had a similar question on SMS recently, and SF Support informed us about undocumented personalization strings for MobileConnect ( SmsJobID
SmsBatchID _subscriberkey), so try reaching out to support. And if you get an answer PLEASE LET US KNOW :)

Support mentioned that for now (2024-11-22) there is no way to retrieve the SendIdentifier information using AMPScript and there is nothing planned to allow customers to do so.
However, I created an IdeaExchange topic asking for that functionality:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Qena3UAB/make-sendidentifier-available-as-an-ampscript-personalization-string
Hope it gets available in the future!
